# Eval in a Databinding Control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I know this question has been answered a few times but it just hasn't been the way I've need it.

Basically I have this code:

```
<Engine:WidgetSQLDataSource ID="DS_Hotel" runat="server" SelectCommand="site.GetHotelList" />

    <asp:Repeater ID="rp_GuestHotelInfo" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS_Hotel">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <% if (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TreeID")) == PrimaryNavigation1.ParentID) { %>
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img width="226" height="68" src="<%# Eval("Logo") %>" alt="<%# Eval("HotelName") %>" /></a>
            <% } %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

What I am trying to do is change the logo based on the currents pages parent id.

However I'm getting an error saying that:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

Any ideas how I can tackle this issue?
Thanks,
T.J.

Comment: Rather than try to filter the items from the template you should really be performing that filter on the actual data source on the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeater, in webform at least, does not support the "if" statement, instead you can use the "ternary" operator, for example: string src = (a==b) ? "equal":"diferent"; 
So your code may be replaced by this:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img width="226" height="68" 
            src='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TreeID")) == PrimaryNavigation1.ParentID) ? Eval("Logo") : "" %>'  
            alt="<%# Eval("HotelName") %>"
        />
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
This answer is exactly what I was looking for.

I used the same concept to hide the inactive ones too!
Much appreciated